# Transfer HTML Table data into asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a stored procedure that select data in my table.

```
USE [accounting2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Get_Remittance]    Script Date: 05/10/2017 09:32:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Get_Remittance]
as
SELECT 
    ID as '#'
    ,COMPNAME as 'Company Name'         
   ,[REMITTYPE] as 'Remittance Type'
   ,SCHEDPAY as 'Schedule Pay'
   ,CONVERT(varchar(10),[GEN_DATE], 101) AS 'Date Generated'
   ,CONVERT(varchar(10),[PAID_DATE], 101) AS 'Date Paid'
   ,CONVERT(varchar(10),[TRANS_DATE], 101) AS 'Date Transmitted'
   ,[MONTH] as 'Applicable Month'

  FROM [accounting2].[dbo].[GMB_REMITTANCE]
```

and this is the way how i populate data in my tablE (HTML Table) during page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Display_RemittanceReport();

                string query = "Get_Remittance";
                DataTable dt = new CLS_SProd().ALLRemittance(query);
                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();


                html.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                html.Append("<tr>");
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append("");
                html.Append("</th>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<th>");
                    html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                    html.Append("</th>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");


                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    html.Append("<tr>");
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    //html.Append(@"<img src='Images\Pencil.ico' alt='' border=1 height=18 width=16 class='click - to - select'></img>");
                    html.Append("<a href='#'>Select</a>");
                    html.Append("</td>");
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {

                        html.Append("<td>");
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        html.Append("</td>");
                    }
                    html.Append("</tr>");
                }


                html.Append("</table>");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });

                Display_CompName();
            }
        }
```

Based on th code above i created a table based on my data and there will be always a link called select.

My question is how can i use that select to transfer current row in my textbox?
and here is my textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox7_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**Updated Code**

HTML

```
<title>GMB Monitoring System</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[actor=popup]').on('click', function () {
        document.getElementById('TextBox21').value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    });
</script>

<%-- and so on...... --%>
```

C#

```
 private void Display_Remittance()
        {
            //Display Remittance Report

            string query = "Get_Remittance";
            DataTable dt = new CLS_SProd().ALLRemittance(query);
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();


            html.Append("<table border = '1'");
            html.Append("<tr>");
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append("Select");
            html.Append("</th>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //Working Code
                //html.Append("<td>");
                //html.Append(@"<img src='Images\Pencil.ico' alt='' border=1 height=18 width=16 class='click - to - select'></img>");
                //html.Append("<a href='#'>Select</a>");
                // html.Append("<a actor='popup' href='#'>Select</a>");
                //html.Append("</td>");

                html.Append("<tr>");
                html.Append("<td><a actor='popup' href='#'>Select</a></td>");

                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
            html.Append("</table>");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
```

TYSM

Comment: what do you want the textbox to show; The raw html?

Comment: yes sir the data inside of the html table

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
html.Append("<td><a actor='popup' href='#'>Select</a></td>");
```

And than in javascript
1.] to Get nth cell value in cell

```
 $('a[actor=popup]').on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('TextBox7').value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
  });
```

2.] to get whole row

```
 $('a[actor=popup]').on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('TextBox7').value = $(this).closest('tr').text();
  });
```

Comment: If you feel any problem in putting the code together in your file than let me know @Paul Edward Pagente

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you asap :)

Comment: Sir not working what happens is in the end of link there is an # but not trans. in textbox

Comment: trans ?? what actually you got is unclear , there is no value in textbox ??

Comment: i mean sir transfered, theres no value in textbox.

Comment: hi sir its me im the one who post the question. Im out of office now so I cant give it to you maybe tomorrow morning but if you still want, I still remember that i put the code above in `<script>` tag below my `<style>` tag then replace the `html.Append("<a href='#'>Select</a>");` with `html.Append("<td><a actor='popup' href='#'>Select</a></td>");` based on the code i posted. I think its working coz when i click select there is a `#` at the end of my website link. looking forward to talk to you tomorrow. thnx

Comment: Sir Good Morning Please see the updated post(added the code using your code) im trying to transfer the data from the column next to select link in textbox21

Comment: You are missing actor='popup' in your anchor tag(C# code) , selector is not there that's why it is not invoking the java script code

Comment: sir what do u mean anchor tag?

Comment: @ShadowFiend ohh dear , you have to use html.Append("<a actor='popup' href='#'>Select</a>") , but you are using html.Append("<a href='#'>Select</a>") . Check now

Comment: @ShadowFiend Can you update it in question , i cant see your updates

Comment: @Saurabh sir the updated code is below the word **Updated Code**

Comment: @ShadowFiend , Also post the html of table which is getting generated , check view source of the page

Answer (score 0):

You could do it sever side by retrieving the specific row again from db based on some id but I would try a client side approach with JQuery.

Client side approach:

1) Add a unique id to each row E.g. id="row_1"

2) Write a JavaScript function that takes as a parameter the row id. Then using JQuery to access the contents of that specifc row copy the data to the textbox.

3) Add the JavaScript to call the function from each select link E.g. onclick="javascript:fill_function('row_1');"

Comment: Sir can you give me a code? Its hard for a beginner like me to understand this

Comment: can u pls assist me sir?